# Embed node.js, socket.io and mongodb chat code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I have created a chat application using **node.js, socket.io and mongodb** and hosted it on a server.

Now I want to use that chat application on different website by taking a link or code and embed it in normal website that is hosted in another server that uses apache.